# GoSublime go to definition

Tags: go, sublimetext2

Does `go to definition` work in GoSublime 2 or 3 ?

I get only

```
GsDoc: no docs found
```

It is mentioned that that feature is available 
https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime

and documented
https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/blob/master/USAGE.md

But I found similar error reports year or two years old.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This go to definition only works with expression `pkgname.Funcname`, but the design(general interaction)  is not implemented.

[image]

By other way you must have the source code in the `GOPATH` or `GOROOT`, if not GoSublime cannot find your code.

You can read more about at:
https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/issues/62

Comment: It seems method lookup is still not supported. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [GoGuru](https://github.com/alvarolm/GoGuru). I have made a [blog post](https://medium.com/@arshamshirvani/super-charge-your-sublime-text-for-golang-development-3239d9c376bb) how to setup ST3 for golang development.